# Setting up git, path errors when pushing/cloning from local to NAS

Tags: git, synology

I'm setting up a NAS server with Git for the first time, so please forgive the noobish questions (it also means I am super thankful for any detailed explanations you can give me, because I am kind of a fish out of water on this).

Here's what I've done so far:

1. List item
2. Set up NAS
3. Installed git, following these instructions: http://www.wonko.de/2010/04/set-up-git-on-synology-nas.html (I made it until the end of step 5)
4. Have git working on my local computer (did `git init` and initial commit)

Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to do step 6 of that guide (http://www.wonko.de/2010/04/set-up-git-on-synology-nas.html) so that I can use `git clone` and `git push` to send commits of my local to my NAS.

I read the comments below that post, and have tried the following:

- Created a file called `environment` saved in my local home folder: `.ssh/environment`
  with the following typed in there:
  `PATH=/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin`
- Logged in to my NAS using `ssh://root@ipaddresstonas`, and typed:
  `cd /usr/bin`
  `ln -s /opt/bin/git*`

However, I keep getting these results:

Terminal on my local machine:

```
$ git remote -v
nas ssh://me@192.168.0.124/volume1/path/to/test (fetch)
nas ssh://me@192.168.0.124/volume1/path/to/test (push)
$ git push nas master
me@192.168.0.124's password: 
sh: git-receive-pack: not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And when I try typing `$PATH` in my local machine:

```
$ $PATH
-bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin: No such file or directory
```

On my NAS:

```
nas> cd /volume1/path/to/test
nas> ls
test.git

nas> $PATH
-sh: /opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/syno/bin: not found
```

Also, just a note: I'm using Synology DS212J, which I think uses "BusyBox" if that's any help.

I'm really confused on how to set up git to work with my NAS...how I can push to my NAS, how I can clone (or `svn checkout` equivalent) onto another computer etc.

Answer (score 1):

The path in unix is a variable which contains the locations for various programs.

If you type in a command like `whoami`, the shell looks at all the folders listed in your $PATH.

Go ahead and type `which whoami` in your shell. You will see that whoami is likely located in `/usr/bin/whoami`.

By having `/usr/bin` in your path, it makes it so you can just type `whoami` instead of `/usr/bin/whoami`. It is kind of like having a shortcut.

The article you are reading shows that `git-upload-pack` installs to a location that the shell doesn't automatically look in for executables. You need to add `/opt/bin` and `/opt/sbin` to your path so the shell can 'find' `git-upload-pack`

There are multiple ways to add a directory to a path. I prefer to put it in /etc/profile.d however it appears that busy box does not 'look' in that directory. Instead, it will need to be added to the ~/.ssh/environment file. The environment file is parsed when a user connects over ssh to the server.

---

**Step 6**

Use a text editor to edit the following file (it likely doesn't exist yet)

```
/home/<yourUser>/.ssh/environment
```

Add the following line to /home//.ssh/environment

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin:/opt/bin
```

Then edit the following file (you will need to be root to do this)

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

In that file, you will find the phrase `#PermitUserEnvironment no`

Remove the comment (#) and change no to yes

Restart your ssh service, or just reboot the whole device.

You can test that it worked, but running the following command

```
echo $PATH |grep '/opt/bin'
```

If it returns something, then everything should work.

Answer (score -1):

[set up an rsa key](http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html). Add the source IP to the list of trusted ones on the remote. Generate a key without a password. [Run the git daemon on the other machine](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/git-daemon.1.html).

Test your authentication with `ssh` on the client machine.

Comment: Could you go over that in more detail please?  I have actually already generated the key, and edited it into the root/.ssh/authorized_keys file of the NAS.

Comment: updated my answer with links.